# Dispatching function calls on different formats of maps

Tags: clojure, multimethod

I'm writing an agar.io clone. I've lately seen a lot of suggestions to limit use of records (like [here](http://discuss.purelyfunctional.tv/t/when-to-use-map-vs-defrecord/933/4)), so I'm trying to do the whole project only using basic maps.`*`

I ended up creating constructors for different "types" of bacteria like

```
(defn new-bacterium [starting-position]
  {:mass 0,
   :position starting-position})

(defn new-directed-bacterium [starting-position starting-directions]
  (-> (new-bacterium starting-position)
      (assoc :direction starting-directions)))
```

The "directed bacterium" has a new entry added to it. The `:direction` entry will be used to remember what direction it was heading in.

**Here's the problem**: I want to have *one* function `take-turn` that accepts the bacterium and the current state of the world, and returns a vector of `[x, y]` indicating the offset from the current position to move the bacterium to. I want to have a single function that's called because I can think right now of at *least* three kinds of bacteria that I'll want to have, and would like to have the ability to add new types later that each define their own `take-turn`.

A `Can-Take-Turn` protocol is out the window since I'm just using plain maps.

A `take-turn` multimethod seemed like it would work at first, but then I realized that I'd have no dispatch values to use in my current setup that would be extensible. I could have `:direction` be the dispatch function, and then dispatch on `nil` to use the "directed bacterium"'s `take-turn`, or default to get the base aimless behavior, but that doesn't give me a way of even having a third "player bacterium" type.

The only solution I can think of it to require that all bacterium have a `:type` field, and to dispatch on it, like:

```
(defn new-bacterium [starting-position]
  {:type :aimless
   :mass 0,
   :position starting-position})

(defn new-directed-bacterium [starting-position starting-directions]
  (-> (new-bacterium starting-position)
      (assoc :type :directed,
             :direction starting-directions)))

(defmulti take-turn (fn [b _] (:type b)))

(defmethod take-turn :aimless [this world]
  (println "Aimless turn!"))

(defmethod take-turn :directed [this world]
  (println "Directed turn!"))

(take-turn (new-bacterium [0 0]) nil)
Aimless turn!
=> nil

(take-turn (new-directed-bacterium [0 0] nil) nil)
Directed turn!
=> nil
```

But now I'm back to basically dispatching on type, using a slower method than protocols. Is this a legitimate case to use records and protocols, or is there something about mutlimethods that I'm missing? I don't have a lot of practice with them.

---

`*` I also decided to try this because I was in the situation where I had a `Bacterium` record and wanted to create a new "directed" version of the record that had a single field `direction` added to it (inheritance basically). The original record implemented protocols though, and I didn't want to have to do something like nesting the original record in the new one, and routing all behavior to the nested instance. Every time I created a new type or changed a protocol, I would have to change all the routing, which was a lot of work.

Comment: I ended up going with the "dispatch on `:type`" idea for the time being, and it seems to be going well. I still don't know if it's best practice, but I think it will work fine.

Answer (score 2):

You can use *example-based multiple dispatch* for this, as explained in [this blog post](http://ostlund.rocks/posts/2018-09-14-ebmd/). It is certainly not the most performant way to solve this problem, but arguably more flexible than multi-methods as it does not require you to declare a dispatch-method upfront. So it is open for extension to any data representation, even other things than maps. If you need performance, then multi-methods or protocols as you suggest, is probably the way to go.

First, you need to add a dependency on `[bluebell/utils "1.5.0"]` and require `[bluebell.utils.ebmd :as ebmd]`. Then you declare constructors for your data structures (copied from your question) and functions to test those data strucutres:

```
(defn new-bacterium [starting-position]
  {:mass 0
   :position starting-position})

(defn new-directed-bacterium [starting-position starting-directions]
  (-> (new-bacterium starting-position)
      (assoc :direction starting-directions)))

(defn bacterium? [x]
  (and (map? x)
       (contains? x :position)))

(defn directed-bacterium? [x]
  (and (bacterium? x)
       (contains? x :direction)))
```

Now we are going to register those datastructures as so called *arg-specs* so that we can use them for dispatch:

```
(ebmd/def-arg-spec ::bacterium {:pred bacterium?
                                :pos [(new-bacterium [9 8])]
                                :neg [3 4]})

(ebmd/def-arg-spec ::directed-bacterium {:pred directed-bacterium?
                                         :pos [(new-directed-bacterium [9 8] [3 4])]
                                         :neg [(new-bacterium [3 4])]})
```

For each arg-spec, we need to declare a few *example values* under the `:pos` key, and a few non-examples under the `:neg` key. Those values are used to resolve the fact that a `directed-bacterium` is *more specific* than just a `bacterium` in order for the dispatch to work properly.

Finally, we are going to define a polymorphic `take-turn` function. We first declare it, using `declare-poly`:

```
(ebmd/declare-poly take-turn)
```

And then, we can provide different implementations for specific arguments:

```
(ebmd/def-poly take-turn [::bacterium x
                          ::ebmd/any-arg world]
  :aimless)

(ebmd/def-poly take-turn [::directed-bacterium x
                          ::ebmd/any-arg world]
  :directed)
```

Here, the `::ebmd/any-arg` is an arg-spec that matches any argument. The above approach is open to extension just like multi-methods, but does not require you to declare a `:type` field upfront and is thus more flexible. But, as I said, it is also going to be slower than both multimethods and protocols, so ultimately this is a trade-off.

Here is the full solution: https://github.com/jonasseglare/bluebell-utils/blob/archive/2018-11-16-002/test/bluebell/utils/ebmd/bacteria_test.clj

Answer (score 2):

Dispatching a multimethod by a `:type` field is indeed polymorphic dispatch that could be done with a protocol, but using multimethods allows you to dispatch on *different* fields. You can add a second multimethod that dispatches on something other than `:type`, which might be tricky to accomplish with a protocol (or even multiple protocols).

Since a multimethod can dispatch on anything, you could use a set as the dispatch value. Here's an alternative approach. It's not fully extensible, since the keys to select are determined within the dispatch function, but it might give you an idea for a better solution:

```
(defmulti take-turn (fn [b _] (clojure.set/intersection #{:direction} (set (keys b)))))

(defmethod take-turn #{} [this world]
  (println "Aimless turn!"))

(defmethod take-turn #{:direction} [this world]
  (println "Directed turn!"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Fast paths exist for a reason, but Clojure doesn't stop you from doing anything you want to do, per say, including ad hoc predicate dispatch. The world is definitely your oyster. Observe this super quick and dirty example below.

First, we'll start off with an atom to store all of our polymorphic functions:

```
(def polies (atom {}))
```

In usage, the internal structure of the `polies` would look something like this:

```
{foo ; <- function name
 {:dispatch [[pred0 fn0 1 ()] ; <- if (pred0 args) do (fn0 args)
             [pred1 fn1 1 ()]
             [pred2 fn2 2 '&]]
  :prefer {:this-pred #{:that-pred :other-pred}}}
 bar
 {:dispatch [[pred0 fn0 1 ()]
             [pred1 fn1 3 ()]]
  :prefer {:some-pred #{:any-pred}}}}
```

Now, let's make it so that we can `prefer` predicates (like `prefer-method`):

```
(defn- get-parent [pfn x] (->> (parents x) (filter pfn) first))

(defn- in-this-or-parent-prefs? [poly v1 v2 f1 f2]
  (if-let [p (-> @polies (get-in [poly :prefer v1]))]
    (or (contains? p v2) (get-parent f1 v2) (get-parent f2 v1))))

(defn- default-sort [v1 v2]
  (if (= v1 :poly/default)
    1
    (if (= v2 :poly/default)
      -1
      0)))

(defn- pref [poly v1 v2]
  (if (-> poly (in-this-or-parent-prefs? v1 v2 #(pref poly v1 %) #(pref poly % v2)))
    -1
    (default-sort v1 v2)))

(defn- sort-disp [poly]
  (swap! polies update-in [poly :dispatch] #(->> % (sort-by first (partial pref poly)) vec)))

(defn prefer [poly v1 v2]
  (swap! polies update-in [poly :prefer v1] #(-> % (or #{}) (conj v2)))
  (sort-disp poly)
  nil)
```

Now, let's create our dispatch lookup system:

```
(defn- get-disp [poly filter-fn]
  (-> @polies (get-in [poly :dispatch]) (->> (filter filter-fn)) first))

(defn- pred->disp [poly pred]
  (get-disp poly #(-> % first (= pred))))

(defn- pred->poly-fn [poly pred]
  (-> poly (pred->disp pred) second))

(defn- check-args-length [disp args]
  ((if (= '& (-> disp (nth 3) first)) >= =) (count args) (nth disp 2)))

(defn- args-are? [disp args]
  (or (isa? (vec args) (first disp)) (isa? (mapv class args) (first disp))))

(defn- check-dispatch-on-args [disp args]
  (if (-> disp first vector?)
    (-> disp (args-are? args))
    (-> disp first (apply args))))

(defn- disp*args? [disp args]
  (and (check-args-length disp args)
    (check-dispatch-on-args disp args)))

(defn- args->poly-fn [poly args]
  (-> poly (get-disp #(disp*args? % args)) second))
```

Next, let's prepare our define macro with some initialization and setup functions:

```
(defn- poly-impl [poly args]
  (if-let [poly-fn (-> poly (args->poly-fn args))]
    (-> poly-fn (apply args))
    (if-let [default-poly-fn (-> poly (pred->poly-fn :poly/default))]
      (-> default-poly-fn (apply args))
      (throw (ex-info (str "No poly for " poly " with " args) {})))))

(defn- remove-disp [poly pred]
  (when-let [disp (pred->disp poly pred)]
    (swap! polies update-in [poly :dispatch] #(->> % (remove #{disp}) vec))))

(defn- til& [args]
  (count (take-while (partial not= '&) args)))

(defn- add-disp [poly poly-fn pred params]
  (swap! polies update-in [poly :dispatch]
    #(-> % (or []) (conj [pred poly-fn (til& params) (filter #{'&} params)]))))

(defn- setup-poly [poly poly-fn pred params]
  (remove-disp poly pred)
  (add-disp poly poly-fn pred params)
  (sort-disp poly))
```

With that, we can finally build our polies by rubbing some macro juice on there:

```
(defmacro defpoly [poly-name pred params body]
  `(do (when-not (-> ~poly-name quote resolve bound?)
         (defn ~poly-name [& args#] (poly-impl ~poly-name args#)))
     (let [poly-fn# (fn ~(symbol (str poly-name "-poly")) ~params ~body)]
       (setup-poly ~poly-name poly-fn# ~pred (quote ~params)))
     ~poly-name))
```

Now you can build arbitrary predicate dispatch:

```
;; use defpoly like defmethod, but without a defmulti declaration
;;   unlike defmethods, all params are passed to defpoly's predicate function
(defpoly myinc number? [x] (inc x))

(myinc 1)
;#_=> 2

(myinc "1")
;#_=> Execution error (ExceptionInfo) at user$poly_impl/invokeStatic (REPL:6).
;No poly for user$eval187$myinc__188@5c8eee0f with ("1")

(defpoly myinc :poly/default [x] (inc x))

(myinc "1")
;#_=> Execution error (ClassCastException) at user$eval245$fn__246/invoke (REPL:1).
;java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Number

(defpoly myinc string? [x] (inc (read-string x)))

(myinc "1")
;#_=> 2

(defpoly myinc
  #(and (number? %1) (number? %2) (->> %& (filter (complement number?)) empty?))
  [x y & z]
  (inc (apply + x y z)))

(myinc 1 2 3)
;#_=> 7

(myinc 1 2 3 "4")
;#_=> Execution error (ArityException) at user$poly_impl/invokeStatic (REPL:5).
;Wrong number of args (4) passed to: user/eval523/fn--524

; ^ took the :poly/default path
```

And when using your example, we can see:

```
(defn new-bacterium [starting-position]
  {:mass 0,
   :position starting-position})

(defn new-directed-bacterium [starting-position starting-directions]
  (-> (new-bacterium starting-position)
      (assoc :direction starting-directions)))

(defpoly take-turn (fn [b _] (-> b keys set (contains? :direction)))
  [this world]
  (println "Directed turn!"))

;; or, if you'd rather use spec
(defpoly take-turn (fn [b _] (->> b (s/valid? (s/keys :req-un [::direction])))
  [this world]
  (println "Directed turn!"))

(take-turn (new-directed-bacterium [0 0] nil) nil)
;#_=> Directed turn!
;nil

(defpoly take-turn :poly/default [this world]
  (println "Aimless turn!"))

(take-turn (new-bacterium [0 0]) nil)
;#_=> Aimless turn!
;nil

(defpoly take-turn #(-> %& first :show) [this world]
  (println :this this :world world))

(take-turn (assoc (new-bacterium [0 0]) :show true) nil)
;#_=> :this {:mass 0, :position [0 0], :show true} :world nil
;nil
```

Now, let's try using `isa?` relationships, a la `defmulti`:

```
(derive java.util.Map ::collection)

(derive java.util.Collection ::collection)

;; always wrap classes in a vector to dispatch off of isa? relationships
(defpoly foo [::collection] [c] :a-collection)

(defpoly foo [String] [s] :a-string)

(foo [])
;#_=> :a-collection

(foo "bob")
;#_=> :a-string
```

And of course we can use `prefer` to disambiguate relationships:

```
(derive ::rect ::shape)

(defpoly bar [::rect ::shape] [x y] :rect-shape)

(defpoly bar [::shape ::rect] [x y] :shape-rect)

(bar ::rect ::rect)
;#_=> :rect-shape

(prefer bar [::shape ::rect] [::rect ::shape])

(bar ::rect ::rect)
;#_=> :shape-rect
```

Again, the world's your oyster! There's nothing stopping you from extending the language in any direction you want.